# C# Generic Class Types and IComparable, cannot compare type T

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree in C# using generics, but I have no idea how to implement the `IComparable` interface. I cannot compare generic type T so I don't know how to implement `CompareTo()` function.

Here is the code:

```
public class BSTNode<T> : IComparable<BSTNode<T>>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public BSTNode<T> LeftChild { get; private set; }
    public BSTNode<T> RightChild { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

When trying to implement `public void Insert(BSTNode<T> node)`, I need to compare `Data` property, but I get an error saying I cannot compare generic types T.

I tried to implement the IComparable interface but in the CompareTo function, it's the same you cannot compare to T error. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You should probably make sure that `T` implements `IComparable` as well.

Comment: I saw that question, but I get an error saying that the type T does not have a CompareTo member function.

Comment: `public class BSTNode<T> : IComparable<BSTNode<T>> where T : IComparable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a constraint to your generic type, that will work.

```
public class BSTNode<T> : IComparable<BSTNode<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public BSTNode<T> LeftChild { get; private set; }
    public BSTNode<T> RightChild { get; private set; }

    public int CompareTo(BSTNode<T> other)
    {
        return this.Data.CompareTo(other.Data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a generic type constraint:

```
public class BSTNode<T> : IComparable<BSTNode<T>>
    where T : IComparable<T>
```

That will let you call `CompareTo` on `Data`.